# Large Number of 206 codes in Access Log

Tags: web-server, log-files, logging

I'm finding a lot of 206 access codes in my Apache access log. After looking at the access log it seems that a number of IPs would hit the server multiple time for partial content on a number of large files (100MB - 300MB). The hits would last for a couple of hours and then stop so I can't block individual IPs. This is increasing the amount of data transferred and making me reach my limit.

Does this make sense? Anyone else noticing similar behaviour? At the moment my only options seems to be to upgrading my hosting and get unlimited bandwidth.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're seeing the effect of download managers. If you server large files to the public, anyone using something like GetRight to download it would cause that behaviour: Multiple, parallel requests for different parts of the file.

This alone doesn't have an impact on bandwidth, however; the file is only still downloaded once by the client. Consider enabling [mod_logio](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_logio.html) for the site. It's the only way you'll get a true representation of the number of bytes served per request. If you're using the byte counts form the normal log entries, you'll likely get a huge over-estimate of the amount of bandwidth you're actually using.

If you're actually hitting your bandwidth limit, it could be due to just a general increase in traffic.

Comment: I thought of that but one particular IP address made around 2000 request (with code 206) to the same file over 12hrs so I doubt that's the download manager. With regards to increased traffic, the data I have from logs, Google Analytics, etc doesn't justify the amount of data being downloaded.

Comment: Anything common about the User Agent string are you getting in the requests? If it's some kind of bot, it might be easier to use mod_rewrite to 403 the requests from them. The other option is to put your big downloads behind some sort of authentication, then you can ban the abusers.

Comment: User agents seems to be browsers. Nothing clear that shows its a bot. That is easy to fake so kind of stuck. Looking to get unlimited traffic data. Thanks for everything @SmallClanger